# CORONA: HOW TO HIDE AND VISIBLE A TEXT IN CORONA

Tags: text, hide, coronasdk

I have a function and ... the explanation is that I need to display the text in scaling when my count reaches 10 until then it should be hidden...

```
local text2 = display.newText("BOOM", 60,20)

function scale( event )
   if(appleCount == 10) then
      if text2.contentWidth < 1.5 * display.contentWidth then
         text2:scale(1.02, 1.02)
      else
         text2:scale(0.1, 0.1)
         Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",scale)
      end
   end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",scale)
```

Comment: i am completely new to corona

Answer (score 4, accepted):

text1.alpha=0--it hide the object

text1.alpha=1--it visible

alpha range is 0,0.1,0.2,.,.,1

isVisibile=true or false --it make some time warning

Answer (score 1):

text.isVisible = true  --visibles the text

text.isVisible = false -- hides the text

Answer (score 1):

You can use object.alpha =0 for making it invisible and object.alpha=1 for making it visible;
The alpha value ranges from 0 to 1 .By using this you can control transparency of object.